# Create div inside another div

Tags: jquery, html

I tried to create a div inside another div using append, after etc .. but without success.

The code structure is as follows, a part:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12" id="element-container">

    <div class="row">
          <div class="space-6"></div>
              <div class="col-sm-6 infobox-container" >
                   <div class="infobox infobox-2  infobox-blue" id="infobox_1"></div>
               ....
               </div> !--col-sm-6 infobox-container--!

               <div class="vspace-sm"></div>

               <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
      </div> !--end row--!
```

I need to insert a new div with a text after or before "vspace-sm" . I tried:

```
$('.row').find('.row')
         .find('.infobox-container')
         .after('<div class="box-disabled-container"></div>')
         .text('text text text')
```

Comment: Your code does insert the div, though I don't think you're setting the text where you think you are.  Is the actual issue in the fact that `text text text` is being added to the wrong place?  http://jsfiddle.net/sEEq3/

Answer (score -1):

jquery would be like this

```
$('.row').find('.col-xs-12')
    .find('.row')
    .find('.vspace-sm')
    .before( 
        $( '<div class="box-disabled-container"></div>' ).text('text text text') 
    );
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Amit12x/yrZ76/)

Comment: I didn't "downvoted", I still haven't  reputation to vote. I believe it was another member or administrator.